# How to align images horizontally with auto width using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am making some social buttons to show horizontally aligned centre in mobile. Now there are 4 buttons and each button is made using an image so it is getting difficult to align those properly.

**This is my code:**

```css
.sc1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.sc2 {
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.sc3 {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
.sc4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*width: 168px;*/
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
.sc4 .facebook-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  height: 32px !important;
  width: 32px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
.sc4 .twitter-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  height: 32px !important;
  width: 32px;
  background-position: -32px 0px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
.sc4 .google-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  height: 32px !important;
  width: 32px;
  background-position: -125px 0px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
.sc4 .instagram-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  height: 32px !important;
  width: 32px;
  background-position: -63px 0px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sc2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sc3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sc1">
  <div class="sc2">
    <div class="sc3">
      <span>Connect with us:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sc4">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="Like us on Facebook">
        <div class="facebook-icon"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.twitter.com" title="Follow us on Twitter">
        <div class="twitter-icon"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Like us on Google+">
        <div class="google-icon"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com" title="Follow us on Instagram">
        <div class="instagram-icon"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should be done to align the buttons in the centre and with equal spacing? This is the current status in which I am able to show those buttons right now.

[image]

If someone wants to see complete code then you can check [it here](https://github.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections).

Comment: Instead of auto width do you mean equal width?

Answer (score 4):

**Floats**

Keeping things centered and evenly 'widthed'

```css
container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsla(214, 72%, 62%, 0.2);
  overflow-y: auto; /* normalizes div height of float parent */
}
imgblock {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center; /* center images */
  padding: 10px; /* if you want to add padding.. */
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1); /* .. or borders .. */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* use this to properly calculate width % */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
imgblock img {
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle; /* makes img true to center, vertically speaking */
}
/* unneccesary styling */ imgblock { cursor: pointer; } imgblock:hover { background-color: hsla(64, 98%, 49%, 0.5); } imgblock:hover img { margin-top: -2px; padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
</container>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/d49a4bnh/2/

---

**Flexbox**

If you meant an even width of the icon containers here is a flexbox solution

```css
container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsla(214, 72%, 62%, 0.2);
}
imgblock {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* centers images */
  flex: 1; /* enlarge each element equally to its maximum */
  padding: 10px;
}
imgblock img {
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
}
/* unneccesary styling */ imgblock { cursor: pointer; } imgblock:hover { background-color: hsla(64, 98%, 49%, 0.5); } imgblock:hover img { margin-top: -2px; padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
</container>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/d49a4bnh/

---

**Inline Blocks**

Here's a possible solution using inline-blocks and percentage widths

```css
container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%; /* set a width so the children can calculate their widths */
  background-color: hsla(214, 72%, 62%, 0.2);
  font-size: 0; /* negates the space inline-blocks add after each element, font bug/flaw */
}
imgblock {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%; /* keeps each img container even */
  text-align: center; /* centers the images */
  padding: 10px; /* if you want to add padding.. */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* use this to properly calculate width % */
}
imgblock img {
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
}
/* unneccesary styling */ imgblock { cursor: pointer; } imgblock:hover { background-color: hsla(64, 98%, 49%, 0.5); } imgblock:hover img { margin-top: -2px; padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
  <imgblock><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fIyyVWZ.png"></imgblock>
</container>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/d49a4bnh/1/

Comment: Thanks for such an explained answer but since I am not using img tag so properties like text-align and vertical-align are really not helpful. Although, the second solution really helped as justify-content bring all the icons to the centre.

Answer (score 1):

OK, to make it work I had to add a couple of things to your code (I also changed a little bit to make it all the right sizes).

I added `width: calc(100% - 20px);` to `.sc1` so that it wasn't 100% of the page + 10px.

I did the same to `.sd2` within the media query.

I added `.sc4 {width: 100%;}` to the media query so it took up all the space it could.

I added `.sc4 a {flex: 1;}` to the main css, meaning each `a` within `.sc4` will take up all the space it can.

Finally, I changed the margin for each `div` to `margin: 0px auto;` so they would appear in the center of the `a` tags.

Here is the final result.

```css
.sc1 {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 5px 0px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.sc2 {
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.sc3 {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
.sc4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*width: 168px;*/
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
.sc4 a {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.sc4 .facebook-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  height: 32px !important;
  width: 32px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.sc4 .twitter-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  height: 32px !important;
  width: 32px;
  background-position: -32px 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.sc4 .google-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  height: 32px !important;
  width: 32px;
  background-position: -125px 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.sc4 .instagram-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  height: 32px !important;
  width: 32px;
  background-position: -63px 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sc2 {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    float: none;
  }
  .sc3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .sc4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sc1">
  <div class="sc2">
    <div class="sc3">
      <span>Connect with us:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sc4">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="Like us on Facebook">
        <div class="facebook-icon"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.twitter.com" title="Follow us on Twitter">
        <div class="twitter-icon"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Like us on Google+">
        <div class="google-icon"></div>
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com" title="Follow us on Instagram">
        <div class="instagram-icon"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: 0 auto` on their parent div to center them horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `<center>` tag around all the social icons. It should look like this:

```html
<div class= "sc1">
                <div class= "sc2">
                    <div class= "sc3">
                        <span>Connect with us:</span>
                    </div>
                        <div class= "sc4"><center>
                             <a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="Like us on Facebook"><div class="facebook-icon"></div></a>
                             <a href="http://www.twitter.com" title="Follow us on Twitter"><div class="twitter-icon"></div></a>
                             <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Like us on Google+"><div class="google-icon"></div></a>
                             <a href="http://www.instagram.com" title="Follow us on Instagram"><div class="instagram-icon"></div></a>
                       </center> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The `<center>` tag was deprecated **years** ago.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified a bit....

....removed floats, changed things to `display` properties, added text align on parent, adjusted margins, got rid of superfluous divs in anchor tags........

```css
.sc1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.sc2 { 
  width: calc((42px * 4) + 16px); 
 /* ^^^^
    icon + it's margin/padding * number of icons -- 
    You can remove the +16px.. 
    that is to compensate for the borders on the 
    elements in this snippet.  
    Ideally it'll be simply ---  
    calc(42px * 4); 
    --- */ 


  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid green; }
.sc3 {
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%; 
  line-height: 32px; /* height of icons */
}
.sc4 {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 100%; 
}

.sc4 a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 5px; }

.facebook-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.twitter-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  background-position: -32px 0px;
}
.google-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  background-position: -125px 0px;
}
.instagram-icon {
  background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
  background-position: -63px 0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sc2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sc3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sc1">
  <div class="sc2">
    <div class="sc3">
      <span>Connect with us:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sc4">
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="Like us on Facebook" class="facebook-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://www.twitter.com" title="Follow us on Twitter"  class="twitter-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Like us on Google+" class="google-icon"></a>
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com" title="Follow us on Instagram" class="instagram-icon"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the perfect answer for this problem of mine. If I simply add

```
.sc4 .facebook-icon, .sc4 .twitter-icon, .sc4 .google-icon, .sc4 .instagram-icon{
    margin: 0px auto;
```

to media query and shift icon classes then it should work properly.

Here is the complete code now.

```
.sc1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    background-color: #3498DB;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.sc2 {
    float: right;
}
.sc3 {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px  0px;
}
.sc4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.sc4 .facebook-icon {
    background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
    height: 32px !important;
    width: 32px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}
.sc4 .twitter-icon {
    background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
    height: 32px !important;
    width: 32px;
    background-position: -32px 0px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}
.sc4 .google-icon {
    background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
    height: 32px !important;
    width: 32px;
    background-position: -125px 0px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}
.sc4 .instagram-icon {
    background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gurjyot/Social-Connections/master/images/social-connections-icons.png);
    height: 32px !important;
    width: 32px;
    background-position: -63px 0px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
    .sc2 {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    .sc3{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .sc4 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .facebook-icon, .twitter-icon, .google-icon, .instagram-icon{
        width: 25%;
    }
    .sc4 .facebook-icon, .sc4 .twitter-icon, .sc4 .google-icon, .sc4 .instagram-icon{
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
}
```

HTLM Code

```
<div class= "sc1">
                <div class= "sc2">
                    <div class= "sc3">
                        <span>Connect with us:</span>
                    </div>
                        <div class= "sc4">
                            <div class="facebook-icon"><a href="http://www.facebook.com" title="Like us on Facebook"></a></div>
                            <div class="twitter-icon"><a href="http://www.twitter.com" title="Follow us on Twitter"></a></div>
                            <div class="google-icon"><a href="http://www.google.com" title="Like us on Google+"></a></div>
                            <div class="instagram-icon"><a href="http://www.instagram.com" title="Follow us on Instagram"></a></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```